# How can I upload images to Google+ via email?

Tags: google-plus, email, images

Is it possible to upload an image to my Google+ profile via email?

All other social services seems to have this feature available, but I can't find it on Google+.

Comment: Is it working with google+ business pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can't**.

It's unfortunate, because there *used* to be a workaround using Picasa (details below), but it no longer works.

This is all moot anyway with the move away from Google+ Photos to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com). Google Photos doesn't have an email option either, but there are other ways to automatically get photos in there.

---

The steps below no longer work, but are left as a legacy.

It *used to be* possible. The key is that you don't do it through Google+, but rather Picasaweb (soon to be *Google Photos*)

1. Go to [Picasaweb](https://picasaweb.google.com/)
2. Click the gear in the upper-right corner and select "[Photos settings](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/settings)"
3. On the "General" tab, there is an option for "Upload photos by email:"
4. Click the checkbox and select a "secret word". The combination of the secret word and your user ID will create a special e-mail address (i.e., {userID}.{secret}@picasaweb.com)
5. Use that e-mail address to e-mail images to your Picasaweb (and, thus, Google+) photos

[image: Picasaweb email options]

The photos appear in the "Drop Box" album, which is the default for newly uploaded photos, and the e-mail subject is used as the caption.

From here, you'll want to move the image to an album you're already sharing or, if you want to share every image you send via e-mail, you can share the Drop Box album with whatever Circles you want and it'll appear in your Stream.

**Note:** Google recently changed `picasaweb.google.com` to redirect to your Google+ Photos. While they do provide a [link to get back to Picasaweb without redirecting](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1) there's no telling how long they'll keep that link around. There is not, at this time, a way to upload photos to Google+ via email.

Comment: I was happy to help.

Comment: If I set my DROP BOX folder to public, newly e-mailed photos still don't post directly to my stream. Any ideas??

Comment: Same Problem here. It works for the whole album for the first time but not for single images. If a new image is posted to an album which is shared to a specific circle, the photos do not appear in the stream of the other users.