# Forward picture attachment into Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

If I get an email with a picture, I want to be able to forward that email and the attachment should go directly into Google photos.
Is that possible?

Comment: Are you working in Gmail? Elsewise this probably isn't possible.

Comment: No. Picasa had a custom email address to forward emails to, and then they were put into an album. Why doesn't Google Photos have the same?

Comment: Because Google didn't implement it. Probably because not enough people used it. Only Google can say for sure. You might be able to do something with IFTTT or Zapier.

Comment: See [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17700/354) to a similar question from when it was Google+ Photos.